# Expose WCF Web service on the internet configuration

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services, wcf-binding

I am trying to expose a webservice written in WCF,  to the open internet but i am having trouble configuring it to be consumed from the external url.

The web service is hosted internally at https://ourportal.internaldomain.intra:9011/FrontEndWS and works well. We have exposed the webservice on https://www.internetdomain.com.mt/FrontEndWS however when accessing it from the external address, the soap URLs still referer to the internal address.

Our settings are as follows. We do not need to expose the webservice internally, only on the internet so this should simplify configuration.

```
<bindings>
 <basicHttpBinding>
   <binding name="LargeMessagingBinding" maxBufferSize="99999900" maxBufferPoolSize="524288000" maxReceivedMessageSize="99999900">
     <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="99999900" maxBytesPerRead="99999900" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
     <security>
       <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
     </security>
   </binding>
 </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
 <serviceBehaviors>
   <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
     <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true"  />
     <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
     <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="6553600" />
   </behavior>
 </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="false" />
```

Comment: Do you have multiple network cards on your machine? Did you try specifying the base address for your service?

Comment: There's no `<services>` tag in your config - you're not defining any services.....

Comment: @hasam khan - No for both questions.

Comment: @marc_s - do I put the external url in the services tag?

Comment: Well - yes - you need to define **how** your service can be reached from the outside world using the (A)ddress, (B)inding, (C)ontract of WCF....

Comment: How is your web service hosted?

Comment: Hi..have u got any solution this? i am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

In order to expose your web service to the external world, you would have the WCF service in a Virtual directory under a website in IIS.

Now your url "`www.internetdomain.com.nt`" would be mapped to a specific IP address (externally accessible) and this IP address is the IP addresss of your server on which the WCF service is exposed.

Any request on this IP is received by IIS and determines on how to serve the request.

If the above is fine then the URL for your WCF service would be:

```
http://www.internetdomain.com.nt/virtualdirectory/FrontEndWS
https://www.internetdomain.com.nt/virtualdirectory/FrontEndWS
```

For the **`https`** case your website would have the 443 https port mapped via **`Edit Bindings`** option and specifies the service certificate it needs to use.

Also you need to define your service with an endpoint in the web.config. Example shown below:

```
<bindings>
 <basicHttpBinding>
   <binding name="LargeMessagingBinding" maxBufferSize="99999900" maxBufferPoolSize="524288000" maxReceivedMessageSize="99999900">
     <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="99999900" maxBytesPerRead="99999900" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
     <security>
       <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
     </security>
   </binding>
 </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
      <service name="SampleWCFService.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="default">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="LargeMessageBinding" contract="SampleWCFService.IService1"/>
      </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
 <serviceBehaviors>
   <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
     <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true"  />
     <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
     <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="6553600" />
   </behavior>
 </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="false" />
```

Check the **services** element in the above configuration. Make sure that the namespace of the service is specified correctly.

Comment: Web Service will be accessible via SSL on https. Would it be possible to use basicHttpBinding for it?

Comment: If you are trying to use basicHttpBinding and then use username authentication it wouldn't work as WCF does not allow username to be passed as clear text on the channel.

Comment: But i have tries it and it worked. To make sure i do not have problems what binding would you suggest here?

Comment: Yes, BasicHttpBinding with username authentication over SSL works. If you do not have SSL then it would not. There are scenarios where the SSL is terminated at load balancer and then the traffic is directed to the website in that cases you cannot have basicHttpBinding with username authentication. The type of binding depends on your requirements. In order for the service to adher to basic profile 1.1 basicHttpBinding should be enough

Comment: thanks. I have tried to define an endpoint address but got the following error:  
No protocol binding matches the given address 'http://domain.com.mt/FrontEndWS'. Protocol bindings are configured at the Site level in IIS or WAS configuration.

Comment: Do you have a svc file for your webservice? If that is the case try domain.com.nt/FrontEndWS.svc

Comment: I think the problem i have is related to site binding. in IIS, the binding is https://ourportal.internaldomain.intra:9011 and apparently I cannot 'hardcode' the endpoint address to https://www.internetdomain.com.nt/virtualdirectory/FrontEndWS/service.svc so it shows at the top of the svc page.

Comment: What do you mean by the binding on IIS is ourportal.internaldomain.intra:9011. Is it that the website is listening for http traffic on 9011 port?

Comment: yes exactly. the environment is in a virtual machine and internet traffic is being routed to it from an ISA firewall. so every request to https://www.internetdomain.com.mt/FrontEndWS  is forwarded to https://ourportal.internaldomain.intra:9011/FrontEndWS

Comment: On your IIS make sure that the http binding is mapped to port 9011.

Comment: I am 99.99% certan the problem is related to an ISA server firewall configuration. the webservice s siting behind a firewall with address and port redirection but we have not figured it out yet.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and now figured out that it was because of the SSL offloader which was infront of the web server. Check with your admin group. We got rid of SSL offloader as we had to make the service up. 
You can refer to the links below

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/distributedservices/archive/2010/06/01/ssl-offloader-using-wcf-4-0-routing-service.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/distributedservices/archive/2010/05/13/wcf-and-intermediate-devices.aspx

Also add host header for https

http://www.sslshopper.com/article-ssl-host-headers-in-iis-7.html