# Expose WCF service hosted in IIS to users

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

I have a server physically located in the US. The OS is Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1.

I create a WCF service and host it in IIS on the server.

Now, while I'm physically in Germany, I want to write a WCF client to the WCF service. First of all, I need to create a WCF client proxy.

All the tutorials I've seen imply that the WCF service and WCF client are located on the same machine. I.e., the tutorials use "localhost" everywhere. In my case it doesn't work.

I know the IP of my server but I don't know what settings should be done to allow any programmer to use the WCF service. I guess it requires special customization of the endpoint at the WCF service and some settings at the IIS to make the WCF accessible by anybody.

Can you please give a piece of advice in this regard?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060947/expose-wcf-web-service-on-the-internet-configuration

Comment: It depends on how you are creating your WCF service.  If you're using a .svc file, and your endpoint contains a Metadata endpoint, you're good to go, so long as you haven't explicitly disabled discovery in the web.config.  Just use visual studio to generate a proxy via the Add Web Service context menu.  This is really ridiculously simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two approaches are available :

- Create a service reference using the add reference , enter your service address should be something like : http://IpAdress/service.svc , or if you have your wsdl file on your local disk , just enter your wsdl file location in the add service address bar. This will generate the proxy class.
- If you have the service contract(interface) just do it programatically using ChannelFactory , you must know your binding and endpoint address as well.

If have any questions you're welcome